# AWS free tier usage is expiring

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using a

> t1 micro instance in aws. and s3 services

.Presently i am in free tier period,but now i got a mail that your free tier is expiring.Then from google i learn that nothing will happend after that also,only it will be charged as standard rates.Can i keep this instance in free tier mode after one year also.for eg by starting another instance and changing in to that with same ip.like that.Can anybody help me out on this.My doubt is from the same account can i experiment the scenario i pointed out above.Can any body help me out on this issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [AWS Free Usage Tier Offer Terms](http://aws.amazon.com/free/terms/):

> These free tiers are only available to new AWS customers, and are available for 12 months following your AWS sign-up date. You will not be eligible for the Offer if you or your organization create(s) more than one account to receive additional benefits under the Offer or if the new account is included in Consolidated Billing.

If you plan to continue running a t1.micro on EC2, you can get significantly 
reduced pricing by purchasing a [reserved instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/reserved-instances/).  Including the up-front charge, your monthly cost for the t1.micro (including 8GB EBS volume) could be around $7-9 per month, but keep an eye on other things like IO, network, and snapshot costs.

Comment: Thanks alot for your time..I have a doubt that can we change the existing one to the reserved one..

Comment: @hacker - you do not need to change anything, _Reserved Instances_ are simply a pricing model that AWS applies automatically to your running instance pool; beware though, that there are still some constraints regarding how purchased reserved instances are matched with running instances (basically instance type, region and availability zone need to be identical), see my answer to [Can Amazon EC2 reserved instances be used with auto-scaling in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12839976/45773) for more details on this and respective pointers to the AWS documentation.